# RewriteRule question

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any way i can use RewriteRule to show these links:

/articles_history.php

/articles_geography.php

as

/articles/history.html

/articles/geography.html

I created a .htacesss file on my root directory and would like to know if the above is possible by placing some kind of code in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /articles/(.+)\.html /articles_$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @NegativeCrack - Yes, the direct URL to the PHP file will still function just fine.

Comment: well, i actually want my browser to display:
http://localhost/yo/articles_history.php
AS
http://localhost/yo/articles/history.html

on the address bar. That's about it!

I placed the .htaccess file in the "yo" folder.
What exactly do I have to do now? 

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @NegativeCrack - Now just go to `localhost/articles/history.html` You need to modify the RewriteRule if you want to have `/yo/` infront

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

In addition to RewriteRule, you also need to usually turn the rewrite engine on by the RewriteEngine directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)\.html$ articles_$1.php [L]
```

And for an arbitrary input:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ $1_$2.php [L]
```